# having issue to recognize the type of data

Tags: jquery

Sorry if this is not proper question but I am asking this because I am stuck. **I am going to add jquery tag for this question because I am using javascript and jquery to read below data. I apologize for this.**

I am reading a data from remote server using jquery `$.get(link, function (data) {console.log(data)});` method. But I am getting a strange sort of data which is neither `json` nor `xml`. Below is the kind of output I am getting

```
Time|Line|Destination|Line code
1408|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1422|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1 
1428|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1442|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1 
1448|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1502|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1 
1508|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1513|290|Veikkola|7290 1 
1522|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1 
1528|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1542|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1 
1548|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1602|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1 
1608|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1622|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1 
1628|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1642|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1 
1648|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1702|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1 
1708|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1722|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1 
1728|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1742|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1 
1748|14|Pajamäki|1014 1 
1802|39|Martinlaakso|1039 1
```

Now please tell me what type of data is this and how can I make it display the way I want it to?

Comment: you want to insert in html format into Dom and display that?

Comment: Hi it seem simply a text file (csv), with pipe char "|" as separator. You should be able to read it line by line. Then, you can split each line with "|" to get youtr data values.

Comment: @user197508 yes I want to insert it into html format into Dom but the way I want to display it.

Comment: @Squiffy how can I read this line by line? could you please show me some example? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you must parse data according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331008/having-issue-to-recognize-the-type-of-data#comment18188815_13331008).
So,you can use several way:

1-use for loop in jQuery and parse data and insert those into DOM.(not good way)

2-use from template-engine,[JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender).(this is Best way)

**Update**

parse data:

```
var allTextLines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
for(var i=0;i<allTextLines.length;i++){
    var entries = allTextLines[i].split('|');
    // ..
}
```

Comment: That `this` link takes me to this(my post).

Comment: @x4f4r i added how to parse data,please see that.